# How to stop my object once a collision is detected in XNA?

Tags: xna, collision-resolution

I have collision detection but I don't know how to stop an object after a collision and then move the object backward.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change the entity's direction and velocity when the collision is detected.

Comment: if i change velocity to 0 for stop the object get stuck and i cant move anywhere because movespeed is updated every frame

Comment: Please consider posting some relevant code, as this may help others to improve their answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Marton's answer you could also let your object "bounce" off the wall by reflecting its velocity vector:

---

[image: vector reflection]

- **V** is the velocity vector of your object
- **N** the normal of your wall
- **R** reflected velocity vector

```
Vector ReflectVector(Vector V,Vector N)
{
    //Save vector lengths to restore later..
    float vLength = V.Length();
    float nLength = N.Length();

    //Normalize
    V.Normalize();
    N.Normalize();

    //R is our output vector
    Vector R = V;

    //"Reflect" the vector using the DOT product
    R = -2 * (V.Dot(&N))*N + V;

    //Restore lengths
    V *= vLength;
    R *= vLength;
    N *= nLength;

    //Return the reflected vector
    return R;
}
```

example usage could be:

```
if(Collision)
{
    Vector N(1,0); //Imaginary wall (Left side)
    ObjectVelocity = ReflectVector(ObjectVelocity,N);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bryan but i dont wanna bounce object u just wanna make him stop and then move in any direction except wall

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to implement a check during your movement code. If the player attempts to move right, check if there is an object that would stop the object moving in that tick and if so move the player next to that object and set the velocity to 0.

For example:

```
if (player.X + movespeed >= wall.X) {player.X = wall.X - xOffset;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions, depending on what kind of effect you want to achieve. Here's a simple 'rebound' solution:

When a collision between object 'A' and the wall is detected, do the following:

1. Get a Vector **V_r** which points from the collision point to A's center point (let's call the center point **P_A** ).
2. Set the object's new position **P_An = P_A + (V_r * d)**, where **d** is a distance. This distance must be so, that after you set **P_An**, the object is no longer colliding with the wall. So **d** depends on your collision detection method. With pixel perfect collision, **d** must be large enough to put **P_An** on a different pixel than which **P_A** is on.
3. Let's name the object's velocity vector right before the collision **V_v**.
4. Set the object's new velocity to  **V_vn = -V_v * c**, where **c** is a constant value somewhere between zero and one. This will provide the effect of some "inertia loss".

Comment: What is A's center point ?

Comment: @bqaq Well, the position of your object's center. If your object is a circle, then it't the circle's center.

Comment: you have code sample of this ?

Comment: @bqaq Not at the moment. Which part can't you implement?

Comment: How to figure out 1st one anyway i dont wanna bounce my object i just wanna stop him when he collide and give him ability to move

Comment: @bqaq The 1st one? You mean the collision point? It depends on your collision detection method. I'm sure you can find tutorials and code samples for that. To give the ability to move: set a bool property of the object (say, 'TouchesWall') to TRUE while it's colliding with the wall. Then if TouchesWall == TRUE, limit the movement to whatever you wish (just rolling along the y axis, for example). Once the object no longer collides with the wall, set TouchesWall to FALSE.

Comment: But how game must know which side object come from before collide ?

Comment: @bqaq Well, from the object's velocity, the elapsed time, and the object's current position. Simple physics :-)